# How to restrict user from accessing pages in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I am very upset with this oracle apex, their is no proper practical example or demonstration on Oracle Apex

I have built one application where I have 4 pages -> `Home , My account , Calculate gross`

If my `Role : Admin and Name : Raj`  … I should have access to all my above pages

If my `Role : user and Name : Bob` … I should have access only to page : Home and Calculate gross and remaining pages should be hide

**Following is my table details  :**  `employee`

```
Name , Age , Role 
Raj  , 24  , Admin
Bob  , 26  , User
```

**Note :** I am using SSO login

Answer (score 3):

You should create **authorization schemes** - it is done within "Shared components" section. For example, you can create the one whose name is "full_access", its type is "PL/SQL function returning Boolean".

Code depends on what "role" and "name" actually represent; I presume that they are stored into some table. In that case, and if you created Apex users whose username matches name you mentioned (e.g. Raj and Bob), that would be

```
declare
  l_role t_users.role%type;
begin
  select t.role
    into l_role
    from t_users
    where name = :APP_USER;    --> APP_USER is username of currently logged user

  return l_role = 'Admin';     --> if role is "Admin", function would return TRUE
end;
```

(Feel free to improve it.)

---

Then go to the page itself, check its (page's) properties - scroll down to the "Security" section and set the "Authorization scheme" property to "full access".

Doing so, any `APP_USER` whose role isn't "Admin", won't have access to that page.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate with a video if possible. It would be a great helpful. I understood but how to do that is not getting on my application

Comment: Impossible, sorry.